# Including an unmanaged native library files to nuget output directory

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

unamanged  shared object (.so file) does not copy to the output directory:

I have .netstandard 2 project that wraps a c++ library(lets call the project wrap.csproj).
That project depends on shared object (libgdal.so).

I want to use this project as a nuget, and therefor, the projects that will reference my nuget should have the wrap.dll and the libgdal.so in the build/publish folder.

I packed this project as nuget.
but projects( dotnet core) that reference this nuget does not get the libgdal.so file just the wrap.dll in the build/published folder and therefore I am getting run time error.

I add this properties to the nuget csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
<None Include="libgdal.so">
<Pack>true</Pack>
<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
</ItemGroup>
```

EDIT: after a little look from the help here of @zivkan I succeed

all I needed to do is to add the packagepath like that:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="libgdal.so">
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>runtimes/linux-x64/native</packagePath>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: If you only want to support SDK style projects, I suggest you look at the [libuv package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Libuv/) and copy what it does. If you also want to support non-SDK style projects (traditional projects, "old-style" projects, whatever you want to call them), I suggest you copy what the [sqlite package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/) does.

Comment: @zivkan thank you! succeed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

all I needed to do is to add the PackagePath like that:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="libgdal.so">
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>runtimes/linux-x64/native</PackagePath>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

(my run time is linux-x64)

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the "Accepted answer". It's the checkbox under the down arrows to the left of the answer!