# In VS2019 nuget doesn't consider referenced projects as lib, but as nuget packages

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I'm using VS2019 community edition.
I have two .net core projects X, Y, X is referencing Y, and I want to package X as a Nuget package, I'm using the package feature in VS2019.
when I try to add X's Nuget package in another project it searches for Y as a Nuget package and not as DLL should be in X.

How can I change this so Y will be added as DLL in X's package?

I tried to add the following to X's project (.csproj):

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage" DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths-&gt;WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference'))" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

But I still get the same result, nuget.exe tries to restore Y as Nuget package not as DLL comes with X's package.

- UPDATE:

Also if Y has another Nuget dependency, it should be considered in X without referencing it directly in X.

Comment: What is your project type, a net framework project or a net standard project?

Comment: .net core projects

Comment: to clarify: what you want is for the nuget package of X to contain X and Y, and not have a nuget package for Y at all?

Comment: @MarcGravell correct, and also if Y has another Nuget dependency, it should be considered in X without referencing it directly in X.

Comment: @Dabbas I have to ask the obvious question: why not either a: just use a nuget package for Y, or b: merge X and Y into one assembly? I *suspect* that what you want is possible via writing your own nuspec by hand from scratch, but... nobody wants to do that, and an additional package reference seems the idiomatic/expected result here

Comment: @MarcGravell you're correct, no one wants to write nuspec by hand :).
Why not merge X and Y or create a package for Y:
In my use case I have 6 projects, only 2 of them are the core libs that need to be used directly in the projects I'm building, why should I create another 4 packages only to reference them with the others? I find it not useful or clean to create packages that can't be referenced solely because they contain functionality that I can use by itself in other projects.

Comment: @Dabbas,any update about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following:
In X's project:

- Go to Dependencies->Projects.
- Right click on Y's project then `Properties`.
- Set `Private Assets` to `All`
  Now this will add Y's dll file in the `lib` folder in the X's `nuspec` file.
  This will work fine if Y doesn't depend on any other Nuget packages that X doesn't know about, because those packages will not be mentioned as dependencies in X's `nuspec` file.

Finally I settled down on this:
Just reference Y, generate package for it too and live with it :'(

Answer (score 0):

> In VS2019 nuget doesn't consider referenced projects as lib, but as
> nuget packages

**Actually**, the new nuget feature which you used and also [PackagePath="lib" function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57397636/12450747) will treat the dll as a nuget dependency rather than an assembly dll.

If you simply want **Y** to be an Assembly DLL rather than a nuget package, these methods won't work. I have tried these methods, and it really made me struggling.

**After a deep research**, I found that the problem is that [dotnet pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-dotnet-cli) will add the referenced project as a nuget pacakge into the main nuget package automatically. Because `dotnet pack` will automatically generates an `Nuspec` file to package the project according to its rules, which treat the referenced project as a Nuget package by default. You can open the `X.nupkg` file and will see like this under `X.nuspec` file:

[image]

**However**, in this pack mechanism, we do not have the right to change the rule.

**Suggestion**

**1)** when you create the `X.nupkg` file using **Pack** Button in **VS2019**, please do some changes to `X.nupkg` manually.

Use **zip** to open nuget compressed package, then open `X.nuspec` file and delete these node:

```
<dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
        <dependency id="Y" version="1.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
</dependencies>
```

**Save the changes** and then use the modified `X.nupkg`.

**2)** Or you should create a custom nuspec file based on our needs and rules manually to guidance the nuget pack process.

Try to use this `nuspec` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>xxx</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>xx</title>   
    ..................    
  </metadata>

<files>
<file src="bin\xxx\xxx\Y.dll" target="lib\xxx(targetframework)"/>
</files>

</package>
```

> Also if Y has another Nuget dependency, it should be considered in X
> without referencing it directly in X.

**So far**, Nuget does not have the feature to ask the main project whether to use the dependency package dll of the referenced project.

And the dependencies from the referenced projects always exist in the main project.

**Besides**, if you still want these, you could report these problems on [our Team Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) and I hope the Team will check them carefully and give you a satisfactory reply.

Comment: Doing it manually is not a good choice IMHO, I was looking for something done when building the package via VS.