# Copy dependency assemblies into nuget package

Tags: visual-studio, dependencies, nuget, nuget-package

I got a VS 2019 solution with many .Net Standard 2.0 projects.
My main project has a project dependency to another project that has a dependency to a Dapper assembly.
After compiling the main project into a NuGet package, the package hasn't got the Dapper dependency.
How can I include the Dapper assembly into the NuGet package ?

Comment: When you pack your main project, it will make `another project` as a nuget package but however, you did not pack `another project`, so it will miss `another package` on the package source and its content of another package,including `Dapper`.

Comment: So my suggestion is that you should also pack your `another project` as nuget package and then put it into [nuget package source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources).

Comment: And actually, the `Drapper` assembly exists under the `another project` package and it is  not displayed in the main project, but displayed in `another project` dependency, and installed in the main project along with the dependent project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Copy dependency assemblies into nuget package

When you pack your main project, it will make `another project` as a nuget package because the `main project` references `another project`. You should note that `dotnet pack` will see `another project` as a nuget package but you did not pack `another project` additionally.

**So** it will miss `another project` on the package source and the dependency **Dapper** exists under `another project`.

It is not in the dependency of the main project but in the dependency package of another project.

**Suggestion**

==========================================================

**1)** You do not worry too much about that. You should also **pack** `another project` as a nuget package and then put it into the [nuget package source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources).

Like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Although** the dependency **Dapper** does not show on the main project, it shows under the dependency package. And it is installed into the project along with the dependency project.

=====================================================

**Please note that**:

**Before** you install any version of the package, you should first [clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete the cache packages folder under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget`

[image]

=========================================================

**2)** If you still want to see the dependency **Dapper** under the main project, you should also install **Dapper** nuget package into the main project.

Then pack it and you can see the dependency **Dapper** in it.

=========================================================

**Besides**, if you do not want the referenced project to become a dependency nuget package, but just an assembly dll, you could refer to [this link's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63279147/in-vs2019-nuget-doesnt-consider-referenced-projects-as-lib-but-as-nuget-packag).